# TOGGLE 2 DIVS with a Button (Using Javascript, HTML and CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have 2 divs both with different contents inside and I'd like to toggle between them with a button.

I have here my 2 divs with class "step1Content" and "step2Content" respectively.

```
<div class = 'step1Content'> Content1 </div>
<div class = 'step2Content'> AnotherContent </div>
```

I gave step1Content the style display: block.

```
.step1Content { display: block; }
```

I gave step2Content the style display: none.

```
.step2Content { display: none; }
```

I have a button that would toggle between these 2 to show or hide.

```
<button onclick = 'step2()'>2. Taskeros and Prices</button>
```

And my javascript function:

```
function step2(){
document.getElementByClassName('step1Content').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementByClassName('step2Content').style.display = 'block';
}
```

You'd think the results would be a okay right? Nope, when I click the button it does literally nothing. I have no idea why, any help with this?

Comment: use toggle from jquery: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

Answer (score 1):

The function is `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName` and it returns  `array-like`  collection of elements. so you need to use index `0` here for the first element.

```js
function step2(){
  
 var element=document.getElementsByClassName('step1Content');
element[0].style.display = (element[0].style.display ==='none') ? 'block' : 'none';
 var element1= document.getElementsByClassName('step2Content');
  element1[0].style.display = (element1[0].style.display ==='block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
.step1Content { display: block; }
.step2Content { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class = 'step1Content'> Content1 </div>
<div class = 'step2Content'> AnotherContent </div>

<button onclick = 'step2()'>2. Taskeros and Prices</button>
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`

Comment: `HTMLCollection` is not an `Array`. Note also that `div` elements `display` are not toggled at `click` at `button` at Answer.

Comment: @guest271314 yeah i mean ` array-like`  collection of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that

> getElementsByClassName

will return a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

You can either use **getElementById** or **querySelector**

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function step2(){
        if(document.querySelector('.step1Content').style.display === "none"){
            document.querySelector('.step2Content').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.step1Content').style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            document.querySelector('.step1Content').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.step2Content').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

```css
.step1Content { display: block; }
.step2Content { display: none; }
```

```html
<button onclick = 'step2()'>2. Taskeros and Prices</button>
<div class= 'step1Content'> Content1 </div>
<div class = 'step2Content'> AnotherContent </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle visibility of div then you can use j-query toggle function.
Please read http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#shay").toggle();
});
```

For Toggling two div -

```
CSS - .show { display: block; } .hide { display: none; }

    $("button").click(function(){
      $('#div1').toggle();
      $('#div2').toggle();
    });

</script>
<body>
<div class="hide" id="div1">Hi Div1</div>
<div class="show" id="div2">Hi Div2</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reverse()` to toggle `display` of `div` elements

```css
.step1Content {
  display: block;
}
.step2Content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='step2()'>2. Taskeros and Prices</button>
<div class='step1Content'>Content1</div>
<div class='step2Content'>AnotherContent</div>
<script>
  var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[class^=step]"));
  function step2() {
    divs[0].style.display = "none";
    divs[1].style.display = "block";
    divs.reverse();
  }
</script>
```